# Mapping a C-style quaternion with different storage order with Eigen Quaternion Map

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, quaternions

I am trying to map a C-style array which in my application represents a quaternion with components storage order `w, x, y, z` using an `Eigen::Map<Quaternion>`. The problem is that internally Eigen stores quaternion components in `x, y, z, w` order. Is there a way to somehow "swap" the mapped components of the array, without copying / creating a new object?

I added a small snippet to illustrate my problem.

```
const double q[4];
q[0] = 1.0; // w component
q[1] = 0.0; // x component
q[2] = 0.0; // y component
q[3] = 0.0; // z component

// This maps components in wrong order
Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Quaterniond> q_map(q);
```

Comment: Anything you can demonstrate your own efforts so far providing a [mcve]?

Comment: Not really, but since you can only map a single quaternion and these are not internally vectorized, you don't lose much or anything by making some inline conversion functions.

Comment: @Homer512 `Quaternion*Quaternion` products are actually SIMD optimized: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SIMD.h?ref_type=heads. And I don't know any simple way to map to Quaternions with different layout (you could of course write your own Quaternion class, which derives from `QuaternionBase`, or somehow add an option to the existing class).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simply writing a custom type with conversion methods from and to Eigen's types.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

template<class scalar>
struct CustomQuad
{
    using Scalar = scalar;
    using EigenType = Eigen::Quaternion<Scalar>;

    Scalar w, x, y, z;

    /*implicit*/ CustomQuad(const EigenType& q) noexcept
    : w(q.w()),
      x(q.x()),
      y(q.y()),
      z(q.z())
    {}
    constexpr CustomQuad(
          Scalar w=1.f, Scalar x=0.f, Scalar y=0.f, Scalar z=0.f) noexcept
    : w(w), x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}
    static CustomQuad* Map(Scalar* data) noexcept
    { return reinterpret_cast<CustomQuad*>(data); }

    static const CustomQuad* Map(const Scalar* data) noexcept
    { return reinterpret_cast<const CustomQuad*>(data); }

    operator EigenType() const noexcept
    { return EigenType(w, x, y, z); }

    EigenType toEigen() const noexcept
    { return *this; }
};
using CustomQuadf = CustomQuad<float>;
using CustomQuadd = CustomQuad<double>;

Eigen::Quaternionf test1(const Eigen::Quaternionf& a, const float* b)
{
    return a * CustomQuadf::Map(b)->toEigen();
}
Eigen::Quaternionf test2(const Eigen::Quaternionf& a, const Eigen::Quaternionf& b)
{
    return a * b;
}
CustomQuadf test3(const CustomQuadf& a, const CustomQuadf& b)
{
    return a.toEigen() * b.toEigen();
}
```

As @chtz pointed out, vectorization is a concern. Thankfully, it seems like GCC can handle this. `test1`, where we do one conversion, has exactly one extra shuffle instruction compared to `test2` where no conversion takes place. Both are vectorized. `test3` is similar.

However, you need GCC-10 or newer. Older GCCs or [any version of Clang I could test](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEINIADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/qRJKY4CIWGRLDFx0naYDmlCBEzEBBk%2BfgEVVQI1dQSFEdGx8ba19Y1ZLYNdoT0lfZIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQma27YeMCMAPQA4piobATEAJ772CYaAILPLwq3Xg47bl6f1wAil4mOh3iYAOxWV47WE7Ki0VBMAg7ADupB2qgxdwxAC99tC3jC4acAFR4FgJWh4ZCEUmnX7/IgsYGgiBoBifHZHE5%2BECsgixBhpKjmABsOwAjjMdgxUJhVMsEgR3nCdiA0RBJQA6VEQGZzVVqzFa7WqfWG4lqu6mm0G0hGtW403Og2OvZQyEAEXdHM%2BCoSxEZAJZIPQEHdxvhiORaP2Xq42qoGIRSJRqnjGiTKZjKIeay9WeT0bTO3xBaLMrlCqVKqt6s1qLmJtUzZtd2bztxM3dkKsEJ99c%2ByJpweZrPQpJ2AFkmAlqLmp%2BhkUwq/LFZhlb2oTtiJgCIsGLvMKFBcRA/uAPqiT77Nx/EMT0mPCDL2o9tYWD2DokvNXDxxkB2P0UQfccwynWd5xAktkSXFc1xrTc6z/OE%2B2PA9iCPPdT1iC8CGvJhbwOGCwKBCCXzfVcCW/cF61QBJYmREhuWORgQH5EEz2FAQqH1YCBC5asNy3et0L3TCjx5djOORIURQgdFMWxPEPy/b06NQ2FpL5AV5N4nYiB0/iYOE2tty/CTDx2UkCAQPAFBojTXg0z9NJ0ji9KwkUdhYLxaHZQSUQ82TuJFcUdiYDEYNTOCdiiHsXM9esrKwyKbLHcjQQ4qCIASgBaR4jLYhh9QJcEB3eEKvJ4hgqF8/yzECzlgpKzyuP0uqIqigSWtY3l2rk7zeIihKKsJNVUqPJgMqicqkp/MjQ1BBraDWZquSWiduuioLMuWsEzAlMakomuEpsi7Vit5fipyiK7UGMtSKq9Dg5loTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrB2BQFiWTA9jMNYeFIAhNDeuYAGsQDWAAObUIQATkkDQzDMSRsfRtZJE%2BiEuH0ThJB%2BxGAc4XgFBADR4cRuY4FgJA0EpOhYnIShuYSXm4i2QxgC4CENEpmhaDPJm8rpqJQjqO5ODhpXmHuAB5KJtEqBHuF4bm2EELWGFoVW/t4LAoi8YA3DEWgmcN0gsBYMXxCt128D3KoADdMGd/6FUqLxBTV3hcI%2Br3qSiYgVY8LA6duCkI7mBEmGABQADU8EwVEtcY364f4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQvd0SmDCMFAQcsfQ8CiJnYGYNgQBPXlSADuIOFJrR7QY/JOU4fKtbWHZ8s%2BMEC2ABgvDbiwNFUXhUGH4g8Cwbv9VsTB7CnlwGHcTwmj0YIJmKUo9FyVIBGGPxKefqfugfvpKdaKeOhDGvlkP%2Bp99bVDGN/XocQ/5jDfnoYc9QoFTBgXMcGixlgSHel9WmXtAYcExOjMU%2BUxSSGAs3YAOwJbaizFwHYEBcCEBYusLgMxeAG3HijNGZgaHY0%2BhLdG2MxRrDFJ9MUXB0ZUw4DTUgv1/r4MZszVmVt2YwEQCABYBAEhh35oFHm9BiDhFYCsVQRCSFkOAMgICXAeFrF4JgfARB97oD0KXYQohxBVzcbXNQdNG6kFRPHBIacpHfVkXTfBWsw7aJRKgeqpjiGkPIWLKhEIaHajoRADw%2BjYjQ1hmw5RnDSCozMNjDJXANA43Rp9NYONiYVOkNHGRcid4M1sEojhSMpFmFwfItpnT7TDxSM4SQQA%3D) do a slightly worse job (though Clang still handles `test3` perfectly). MSVC doesn't seem capable of handling this at all and resorts to scalar code; unless I messed up the compile switches.

When doing the same tests with doubles, at least from a cursory look, it seems as if Clang does a better job when compiling for SSE2 and GCC does a better job with AVX. Overall, I think both compilers do their job well enough.